# Hide Completions Matching Against Regexp

Tags: completion

[12.6 Tips for Defining Variables Robustly](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Tips-for-Defining.html):

> ‘`prefix--…`’
> : The variable is intended for internal use and is defined in the file `prefix.el`.
>
> ‘`…-internal`’
> : The variable is intended for internal use and is defined in C code.

These variables that appear in `"*Completions*"` may not be helpful for most common Emacs users (and usually they don't have a docstring).

Any way to filter out them?

---

I tried this:

```lisp
;; `*--*'
(setq completion-regexp-list '("^[^-]+\\($\\|-[^-]\\)"))

;; I don't know how to hide `*-internal'.
```

But Emacs signals an error `Wrong type argument: stringp, nil` whenever I type `TAB` among some characters, for example:

```
co-■-h
```

where ■ stands for a cursor.

---

emacs-version: 28.2
system-configuration: x86_64-w64-mingw32

Comment: Not only `C-h v`, but also several other such help-commands for common users, all provide these variables…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

##### 1 What Regexp to Use

> I don't know how to hide `*-internal'.

- To Filter Out `prefix--*`:

  ```
  \`-?\([^-]+\(-[^-]+\)*-?\)?\'
  ```
- To Filter Out `*-internal`:

  ```
  \(\(\`\|[^l]\)\|\(\`\|[^a]\)l\|\(\`\|[^n]\)al\|\(\`\|[^r]\)nal\|\(\`\|[^e]\)rnal\|\(\`\|[^t]\)ernal\|\(\`\|[^n]\)ternal\|\(\`\|[^i]\)nternal\|\(\`\|[^-]\)internal\)\'
  ```

##### 2 How to Avoid that Error

> But Emacs signals an error `Wrong type argument: stringp, nil`

I've reported this as [bug#64351](https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=64351).  In short, don't set it globally.

##### 3 The Answer to the Question

> Hide Variables for Internal Use in `*Completions*` when `C-h v`

```
shynur> I launched Emacs with “-Q” and evaluate:
shynur>
shynur> (advice-add 'describe-variable :around ;“C-h v”
shynur>             (lambda (advice-added-function &rest arguments)
shynur>               (let ((completion-regexp-list 
shynur>                      '("^\\([^-]*$\\|\\([^-]+\\(-[^-]+\\)-?\\)\\)$")))
shynur>                 (apply advice-added-function arguments))))
shynur>
shynur> to filter out symbols “*--*”.
shynur>
shynur> Then type “C-h v advice TAB”, I can still see some variables
shynur> whose names are “*--*” (e.g., “advice--bytecodes”).

Andreas> Interactive completion runs before the function is called,
Andreas> inside call-interactively.  You need to advice the
Andreas> interactive spec.

shynur> Thanks!  This is a tricky issue to me, because I only want to
shynur> filter when calling “describe-variable”.  I guess I have to
shynur> give up this idea...
```

So

```lisp
(let ((shynur--completion-regexp-list '("\\`-?\\([^-]+\\(-[^-]+\\)*-?\\)?\\'"
                                        "\\(\\(\\`\\|[^l]\\)\\|\\(\\`\\|[^a]\\)l\\|\\(\\`\\|[^n]\\)al\\|\\(\\`\\|[^r]\\)nal\\|\\(\\`\\|[^e]\\)rnal\\|\\(\\`\\|[^t]\\)ernal\\|\\(\\`\\|[^n]\\)ternal\\|\\(\\`\\|[^i]\\)nternal\\|\\(\\`\\|[^-]\\)internal\\)\\'"))
      (functions-for-completion [try-completion
                                 test-completion
                                 all-completions]))
  (seq-doseq (key ["C-h f"
                   "C-h v"])
    (let ((key-original-function (keymap-global-lookup key)))
      (global-set-key (kbd key) (lambda ()
                                  (interactive)
                                  (unwind-protect
                                      (progn
                                        (let ((completion-regexp-list+shynur--completion-regexp-list `(,@completion-regexp-list
                                                                                                       ,@shynur--completion-regexp-list)))
                                          (seq-doseq (funtion-for-completion functions-for-completion)
                                            (advice-add funtion-for-completion :around
                                                        (lambda (advised-function &rest arguments)
                                                          (let ((completion-regexp-list completion-regexp-list+shynur--completion-regexp-list))
                                                            (apply advised-function
                                                                   arguments))) '((name . "shynur--let-bind-completion-regexp-list")))))
                                        (call-interactively key-original-function))
                                    (seq-doseq (funtion-for-completion functions-for-completion)
                                      (advice-remove funtion-for-completion "shynur--let-bind-completion-regexp-list"))))))))
```