# suppress a completion candidate, or configure the sorting of completion results?

Tags: completion, sorting, completion-styles

When I do `M-x bury`, my completion setup (I use fido-mode, along with vertico and marginalia), produces these results:

```
1/95   M-x bury
rmail-bury ...
bury-buffer ...
unbury-buffer ...
(etc etc etc)
```

I don't use rmail, and what I want is `bury-buffer`. But the completion always finds the rmail one first.

I've tried fiddling a bit with [completion styles](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Completion-Styles.html) but the sorting always puts rmail-bury first.

How can I get bury-buffer to "win" over rmail-bury? I want something that either changes the sort order, or outright suppresses the rmail result, or something so that I can type `M-x bury` and have the first result be `bury-buffer`?

Comment: I don't think you need to use both `fido-mode` and `vertico` at the same time. Also, it would be helpful if you share what values of `completion-styles` you tried. I suspect you could use `orderless` with `orderless-initialism`, but I cannot be sure if I don't know what you have already tried.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Hide Completions Matching Against Regexp](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/76273/hide-completions-matching-against-regexp)

Answer (score 2):

Setting `completion-styles` to `(basic)` should make `b TAB` use only prefix completion, which eliminates anything doesn't start with `b`.

---

If you use [Icicles](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles) then you have lots of possibilities for dealing with this kind of annoyance/problem, and without tying your hands for other situations where you don't want to be limited to, say, just prefix completion.

With Icicles:

1. `TAB` gives you vanilla Emacs completion, so it respects `completion-styles`. But you also switch to [other sets of completion styles](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Completion_Methods_and_Styles#PrefixCompletionMethod_vanilla), cycling among them on the fly, using `C-M-(`.
2. You also have multiple completion [*methods*](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Completion_Methods_and_Styles#IciclesCompletionMethods), which go beyond completion styles. And you can, likewise, [switch to other methods](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Completion_Methods_and_Styles#ChangingCompletionMethod) on the fly (using `C-(` or `M-(`, depending on the group of methods you want to cycle).
3. You can set the completion method (which, if `vanilla`, means you can also set the `completion-styles`) to use [*for a particular command*](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Completion_Methods_and_Styles#CommandSpecificCompletionMethods) only. For example, for your `bury-buffer` situation, you could dedicate a particular completion method just for the command bound to `M-x`.
4. You can use [regexp completion](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Apropos_Completions) (which includes substring completion) or various kinds of "flex/scatter" or "fuzzy" completion, to quickly match a pattern.
5. You can [match multiple patterns](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Nutshell_View#ProgressiveCompletion) (of any kinds), to quickly narrow the match set. This is [Progressive Completion](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Progressive_Completion).
6. You can selectively remove individual completion candidates or all candidates matching a pattern -- [chipping away the non-elephant](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Nutshell_View#ChippingAway).
7. You can [sort the current completion matches](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Sorting_Candidates), on the fly, in various ways, including sort orders that you can define yourself.

And there are other Icicles features that you can put to use to simplify getting to `bury-buffer` without being bothered by noise.

Comment: Thanks -- I'll look into icicles. I'm always nervous about "just start using this big complex framework, which is just one of many similar frameworks"; sometimes enabling something like somehow makes many things work slightly differently, and I may not want to put in all the effort into learning a new framework thingy. But, as they say, configuring emacs is not so much a *task* as it is a *lifestyle choice*. I'll see about choosing the "try out icicles" lifestyle. :)

Comment: Understood. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, here's an extremely effective, but very bad answer: just fiddle with the name of the rmail function.

I edited `rmail.el` and changed

```
(defun rmail-bury ()
```

to

```
(defun rmail-xbxury ()
```

which very effectively defeats any substring or similar completion matching when I do `M-x bury`.

(If you have compiled `.elc` files, you'll need to recompile, or delete that, or something, but I'm doing this on Windows in emacs 28 and there's no `rmail.elc` with the `rmail-bury` defun.)

Now, of course, this breaks rmail -- but since I never use that, I don't mind.

In terms of elegance and good coding practice, this is, of course, awful -- but in terms of simplicity and effectiveness, it's excellent...